# Angulartics to track impressions on Bootstrap carousel items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, angulartics

In my Angular app, we have a bootstrap carousel (using bootstrap carousel rather than ui bootstrap carousel for some reasons), items structure as follows

```
<div class="item" analytics-on analytics-event="IMPRESSIONS" analytics-category="{{--}}" analytics-label="{{--}}" ng-repeat="banner in vm.bannerList">
        <a ng-href="{{--}}" analytics-on analytics-event="CLICK" analytics-category="{{--}}" analytics-label="{{--}}">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image: url({{--}});"></div>
        </a>
</div>
```

The click event working fine. But how to track the IMPRESSIONS. The impression event need to trigger when a carousel item becomes active.

I tried to watch the 'active' class using a custom directive but the watch only worked on load time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried and succeeded,

Following custom directive did the job.

```
//ng-track-carousel-impressions
        angular.module('app').directive('ngTrackCarouselImpressions', ['$analytics',function (analytics) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                // create an observer instance
                var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        if (element.hasClass('active')) {
                            //console.log(element.attr('analytics-label'));
                            // emit event track (with category and label properties for GA)
                            analytics.eventTrack(element.attr('analytics-event'), {
                                category: element.attr('analytics-category'), label: element.attr('analytics-label')
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });

                // configuration of the observer:
                var config = {
                    attributes: true
                };

                // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
                var node = element.get(0);
                observer.observe(node, config);

            }
        }
    }]);
```

Usage

```
<div class="item" analytics-event="IMPRESSIONS" analytics-category="{{--}}" analytics-label="{{--}}" ng-repeat="banner in vm.bannerList" ng-track-carousel-impressions>
            <a ng-href="{{--}}" analytics-on analytics-event="CLICK" analytics-category="{{--}}" analytics-label="{{--}}">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image: url({{--}});"></div>
            </a>
</div>
```